# How to determine if something should be an entity or an identifying relationship?

Tags: entity-relationship

I'm trying to sketch out an ERD for booking hotel rooms. I had the "Reservation" as its own entity, so a User makes a reservation, and a reservation is for a room. But I guess it could also be an identifying relationship between the user and the room, as it joins them both. A user reserves a room. The reservation table would have a user_id and room_id. 
I would think other entities should be related to the reservation though, such as payment, rate of cost. Any input would help, I'm quite new to these. Thanks!

Comment: Other details with reservation could be: Date, Number of People in different age group, number of rooms. One more point to note is that there will be 1 to many relationship between. One reservation can be for multiple people and many rooms. More than one person can live in a room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An identifying relationship is the relationship between a weak entity and its parent entity. A weak entity is an entity that can't be identified by its own attributes and has another entity's key as part of its own.

Does this apply to your situation? Is a `User` partially identified by the `Room` they reserve, or a `Room` by the `User` who reserved it? I would think not.

The other possibility is to make `Reservation` a regular relationship. Can a `Reservation` be identified by some combination of the entities it's related to? I don't think so. I imagine any `Reservation` could be repeated at a later date, but dates are usually seen as value sets, not entity sets.

`Reservation` should probably be an entity set.